# WCF ServiceActivationException

Tags: wcf, iis-7

I keep seeing this error on few of our environments:

> System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: Request to the service
>   at '~/TmpServ.svc' cannot be dispatched because the virtual
>   application at '/TmpServ' is shutting down.
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.FailActivationIfRecyling(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String
>   relativeVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)

We are using IIS 7;
the load on the Web server is low, but the error still appears a few times a day.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

In IIS: Increase Process Model / Idle Time-out or set Idle Time-out Action to Suspend. Set Recycling / Regular Time Interval (minutes) to 0.

Use Windows Services to host your WCF service if you can.

Comment: The Recycling / Regular Time Interval has the default value (1740 minutes) and Idle time-out is set to a few hours (and still the error is much more frequent than that value).The second option as I understand would mean re-thinking the architecture of the service. I was wondering of the root cause of the problem.

Comment: You can always add more logging. Enable WCF logging and that might give you some more information.

Comment: In IIS, all options of _Generate Recycle Event Log Entry_ are enabled. Any way, out of these I understand only 'ISAPI Report Unhealthy' would be useful. The error described above is taken from the Windows Event Logs.

Comment: This is how you configure [WCF Tracing & Logging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751526%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Event log is not that helpful.